# set image width with php?

Tags: php

I am creating a custom blog with php. when the user is uploading an article I am having problem  with the images in the post. some images's width are bigger than the main div in my blog (740). I want to use php to check the width of the images if it is bigger than 740 then re-size  the image to 740.

```
<?php
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($article_content);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$imgs  = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
$links = array();

for($i=0;$i<$imgs->length;$i++){
$links[]  = $imgs->item($i)->getAttribute("width");
$image_path = $links[];
$article_source = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image_path));
$image_width = imagesx($image_source);
if($image_width > 740){$image_width = 740;}      
}   

?>
```

so far this is the code that I have. I am not sure how to set the image width.(the image already has its original width)
UPDATE:
I am not trying to save or copy the image. I am trying to access the dom by php and set the image width to $image_width (of all images)

Comment: Doesn't this line handle that? `if($image_width > 740){$image_width = 740;} `

Comment: `$imgs->item($i)->setAttribute("width", $image_width );`?

Comment: @paul well this is setting the width of the image. But it is not setting the actual image width.

Comment: @Rocket should be `width` instead of `src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without saving/copying the image you will have to replace img tags in the HTML document with ones having a width attribute.

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($article_content);

$imgElements  = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
foreach ($imgElements as $imgElement) {

    $imgSrc = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imgElement->getAttribute("src")));

    if (imagesx($imgSrc) > 740) {

        // we replace the img tag with a new img having the desired width
        $newE = $dom->createElement('img');
        $newE->setAttribute('width', 740);
        $newE->setAttribute('src', $imgElement->getAttribute("src"));

        // replace the original img tag
        $imgElement->parentNode->replaceChild($newE, $imgElement);
    }
}

// html with "resized" images
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 2):

From your code I assume that you are using the GD library. In that case, what you are looking for is [imagecopyresized()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php).

Here's an example of what you might want if the image width is  too great:

```
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

imagecopyresized($small_image, $image_source,
        0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $image_width, $image_height);
```

Then `$small_image` will contained the scaled version of the image.

Comment: I am not trying to save or copy the image. I am trying to access the dom by php and set the image width to $image_width

Comment: In that case @Rocket's comment should be what you need.